# Use firefox as the in-app browser instead of chrome

Tags: browser

When I click a link in another app, say "gmail" for instance, it opens up an in-app browser to view it.

When you clock on the top right menu bar, you can see that at the bottom it says "Powered by Chrome".

On another older phone, it somehow used to be "Powered by Firefox". I don't remember exactly how I enabled it. How should I enable it in other phones?

Comment: I assume you are talking about the "WebView implementation" - the embedded webbrowser used by many apps. It can be configured in developer options but Firefox does not show up in the list of available web view implementations (but I only have "Firefox" installed at the moment Mozilla has quite a few different Firefox based browser in PlayStore available, may be one of the other apps can be selected).

Comment: It's not webview implementation. I think it used to be called "chrometabs" but I haven't done android dev in a while so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the default browser as Firefox (it was set to none, because I had disabled chrome) worked.

For firefox, the instructions can be found [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/set-firefox-focus-default-browser-android)

For others, "default apps" menu in the settings is what I had to change for my version (Android P), ymmv.